# Call to undefined method Bcrypt::check_password() - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, bcrypt

I am trying to implement basic login system.

User's password is hashed by bcrypt and stored in database.

In login model, I am trying to pull hashed password from db and match with what user have entered using bcrypt check password.

**Model**

```
function login($data)
    {
        $hashedpass = "";
        $query=$this->db->get_where('voyagers', ['EMAIL'=>$data["EMAIL"]]);
        $result=$query->result();
        foreach($result as $val) {
        $

        $hashedpass = $val->PASSWORD;

        }
          if ($this->bcrypt->check_password($data["PASSWORD"], $hashedpass )) {
         return $result;
         }
         else
         return 0;

    }
```

When I run my project if throws error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Bcrypt::check_password()

Filename: models/Model_Main.php

Line Number: 47

Backtrace:
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why not just use for creating passwords http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php very simular http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-examples and verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Also note: Your filename and classes should only have first letter only upper case if using CI 3 and above explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Was **NOT** me @DKR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself.

In bcrypt.php under library folder, it has checkpassword function instead of check_password.

Changing function name got it worked.

Comment: Isn't that what I suggested bro?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `bcrypt` library in codeigniter if it does not exist, if you have `bcrypt` library in your `application/library` folder add it like this in `constructor`:

`$this->load->library("library_name");` 
you can then call your library like this

`$this->library_name->method();`

You can check Codeigniter [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/libraries.html) on libraries. NOTE: Make sure you to check your library folder if your library file is not there add it there, if your file name is something else you need to call that file name for the library.